# Inputting a string into my code that an int is required and I get a java error how can I fix this?

Tags: java

When I input a string into the code below by mistake as a test, I get a red java error message in my console. However, within my if statement I added an else part which should end the program if the user doesn't input the if statement condition i.e a number between 0-100. Why this is and how can I fix it?

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int decimal = input.nextInt();
        if (decimal > 0 && decimal <= 100) {
            //code 
        }
        else {
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nextInt` method throws an exception if the input is not an integer. If you want to prevent this, just use the method [`hasNextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--) to check before read it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/OK8r3RH I get this error for some reason. Thanks for the post reply.

Comment: Check this link maybe it helps https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextint.htm